# How to import datetools in python?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter

I am using Jupyter Notebook with python 3.8.

I get an error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'datetools' from 'pandas'
```

from the code below:

```
import pandas as pd 
from pandas import datetools
```

I confirm that pandas is installed but I saw that datetools is deprecated.
What can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas datetools module error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50931581/pandas-datetools-module-error)

Answer (score 0):

Pandas datetools may have been removed from the version you are using now in your system.
Try downgrading the pandas if you insist on using datetools, or for better solution, use `datetime` package that will help you achieve results.